# Add a second image in the navbar of a Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following snippet of code:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  shinyjs::hidden(div(
    id = "application",
    navbarPage(
      title = div(img(src="img_1.png", filetype="image/png"), "Indicators"),
      id = "tabs",
      tabpanel("Admin", ...)
      tabpanel("User", ...)
    )
  ))
))
```

I would like to add a second image, let's call it `img_2.png` to the right of the navbar, i.e. at the end of the navbar itself. Maybe the fact that I used `title =` forces me to place only one image in the navbar. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

you can add an additional img tag and an style parameter, that sets the position to the right side:

```
title = div(img(src="img_1.png", filetype="image/png"), "Indicators", img(src="img_1.png", filetype="image/png", style = "position: fixed;right: 20px;"))
```

Comment: I would like to place `img_2.png` to the right of `'Admin'` and `'User'` as well

Comment: this works also with `tabPanel` e.g.: `tabPanel(div("Admin", img(src="img_1.png", filetype="image/png")), ...)`